# SAT Collision detection - Corners fix

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, collision, game-physics, separating-axis-theorem

I'm building a game and I'm currently working on the physics.

I'm using the **SAT algorithm to detect collisions**. The collisions are **between the character** (AxisAlignedBoundingBox) **and some rectangles** (with rotation).

Everything works fine, **except the collision near to a corner** in specific situations. (This is a pretty known problem but I didn't find any good solutions).

[image]
On **Example 1**, in the second scene the character should move upwards (stay on the obstacle).
**It happens to move left.**
On **Example 2**, in the second scene the character **should not get up**. Sometimes it gets.

I know why this is happening, because of **dx** and **dy**, the **Minimum Translation Vector isn't always the wanted one**.

There are several solutions to this problem, but not a really good one (in terms of solving the problem and not creating others!).
I'm willing to even use a totally different algorithm from the beginning.

Please give me a hint about an algorithm better than the SAT, or some workaround.
**THANK YOU!**

Comment: Could you show some code ? What contact normal do you obtain in each case and what do you expect ? (for me the first one should be `(0, 1)` and the second `(-1, 0)`, and that's what you should be getting looking at the minimum translation vector)

Comment: No, there are more aspects than a simple movement. dx, dy, gravity play a part on this. ex. of MTV: (-2, -0.35) -> the character needs to move -2 on the X-Axis and -0.35 on the Y-Axis to get out of collision

Comment: You need to give some code and be more precise about your problem. If you are having problems to handle the collisions it might not be related to the algorithm you use to detect them, but to the way you compute the response.

Comment: no code is needed, and I was totally clear about my problem - which is the response - and NOT the actual algorithm. WHY to post the code of my perfectly working algorithm? I just need to fix the response (not just applying MTV to x and y). You seem not to understand, my problem is NOT programmatic, but algorithmic.

Comment: You will not get overlap if one box has no size. Sounds silly but it works well. Box C has width and height (cw,ch) and so does the obstacle box O (ow,oh). Now find the centers of both and referance them by their center coordinates. Increase the size of box O by adding box C's size ow+=cw,oh+=ch and shrink C to cw=0,ch=0. Now you can apply the test and not get overlap. You can reduce the complexity of the test as now all you have to do is test the center of box C ( a point) against box O.

Answer (score 0):

A picture is worth many words.

The image has two boxes to test the red and the black..

[image]

Note how the center of the black box is always on the darker red box when it is just touching.

You can simplify any AABB test by increasing the size of one box by the size of the other. As long as you referance the boxes position by their centers all works well.

```
// x,y are box centers
var bBox = { w : 100 , h : 50, x : ?, y ? };  // black
var rBox = { w : 200 , h : 200, x : ?, y ? };  // red
```

to test if bBox is inside rBox

```
if(bBox.x > rBox.x - (rBox.w + bBox.w)/2 &&
     bBox.x < rBox.x + (rBox.w + bBox.w)/2 &&
     bBox.y > rBox.y - (rBox.h + bBox.h)/2 &&
     bBox.y < rBox.y + (rBox.h + bBox.h)/2)
    // boxes are touching.
}
```

Also works if boxes are moving. You just test if the vector of bBox movement intersects any of rBox's 4 sides.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Clever workaround, my only concern is about the rotation. The RED box could be rotated, that's why I'm using SAT. I can check before the collision if the character is left - right - above or below the red box (rotated or not) but this doesn't help me much!